# htaccess - Redirect EVERYTHING through php file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|/$)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Above shows my current configuration.

The problem with this is it only seems to be redirecting if a directory or file exists after the folder the htaccess file is in.

How can I rewrite this so it literally just redirects every single request to `api.php` with the full requested path? I'm not looking to see whether directories or files exist in the htaccess file, I can do that in `api.php`, I just want to push all the requests through that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|/$)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^((?!api\.php$).*)$ api.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Lookahead `(?!api\.php$)` means rewrite everything except `/api.php` to `/api.php` with query parameter `url`.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /api.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

make sure you have this before the route

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```